# Swift cellForRowAtIndexPath definition conflicts with previous value

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Below is the code for my tableView, I have an error on the cellForRowAtIndexPath function declaration that says definition conflicts with previous value. A previous stack overflow question has the solution to make the function return UITableViewCell as an optional value but this does not fix the error for me. I also have an error that says viewController does not conform to protocol UITableViewDataSource, but I assume this is because of the error on the cellForRowAtIndexPath method.

I have similar code for a tableView that works, but it was written about a month ago before I updated Xcode. Maybe a recent change in swift is causing the error?

```
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {

        return 1

    }


    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell? {

        let cellIdentifier = "tableViewCell"

        let newCell : TableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier)  as! TableViewCell


        newCell.heading.text = names[indexPath.row]

        return newCell


    }
```

Comment: The real problem is that the function you defined is returning UITableViewCell? and it should be returning UITableViewCell. Remove the ? from the return type.

Comment: yea I tried with and without ? but was still getting errors

Comment: Without ? is definitely the right way.

Comment: I am curious what error message you were getting without the ?

Comment: I was getting the same error, the definition conflicts with previous value both ways. using user5797668 method I got an error that told prompted me to remove the ?, and it worked after I did that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try placing your datasource methods in a class extension like this:

```
extension yourViewController: UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell { // cellForRow stuff 
    }

}
```

Comment: FYI, this is a bit of a hack, not a fix for the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If this is in a UITableViewController, you need to add override to the method:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
```

Comment: I'm using a regular view controller not a UITableViewController so I don't think this will work.

Comment: Is it a subclass of UIViewController? Or one of your own classes?

Comment: All of the code that I posted in the question is within a custom class called ViewController which is a subclass of UIViewController. When I tried your suggestion it says override can only be specified on class members